# how to create a Custom list model in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to create list that shows contacts, each list item shows the name on a line, and the phone number on a second line, and maybe an image or icon. I was thinking of using two labels for that, but i can figure out how to use a custom list model to implement this.

My first attempt was to add a Panel object that contained the info i wanted in the list, then add it to an instance of the defualt list model, but that only turned up the class name in the list.

```
    DefaultListModel Clistmodel = new DefaultListModel();//
    Clistmodel.addElement(Contact);//Contact is an JPanel object
    GroupList.setModel(Clistmodel);//GroupList is the List object
```

this didn't work out at all then i learnt that the default list model only knows how to render strings i think, so i have to create a custom list model, or a custom ListCellRenderer, i don't really know which will solve the problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Already worked through the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating)?

Comment: Yes i've gone through the documentation, but their example was with adding simple values to the list, which i couldn't figure out how to apply to my situation

Comment: *"their example was with adding simple values to the list"*  The example shown in [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) contains an image **and** text.

Answer (score 5):

Your question asks how to create a custom list model, however, that's not what you need (I don't think) as a DefaultListModel will work nicely for you. Rather you will need to work on the renderer. You need to create a non-GUI class to hold your information that each item will display, probably your Contact class, and then create a JList that holds this in its DefaultListModel.

The key for you will be to then create a custom list cell renderer to display the information on multiple lines -- perhaps a JTextArea, or a JPanel that holds two JLabels in a GridLayout. Please understand that the renderer does not display the actual underlying components, but something more akin to a stamped image of whatever components you're trying to display, so it will not have the full behaviors available to it as the actual component would. It will take work, but the [writing a renderer section of the tutorial linked to by user714965](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) will show you how to do this.

Please give it a try, and then if you still are stuck, come on back with your code, your errors, and your questions, and we'll be better able to give you specific help.

Comment: The key here is to understand Separation of Concerns and how this is an application of Model-View-Controller. To the uninitiated, this may seem like extraneous work. Once one understands that what something is is separate from how it can be presented, these tutorials make more sense.